# Objective C HTTP Post Request Parameters Getting Lost Between App and Server

Tags: objective-c, xcode, post

I'm trying to send a post request from my iOS app to the server. The request works when using curl:

```
curl -d "uid=1&type=robbery&x=41.66505&y=-93.73046" http://thawing-ravine-5632.herokuapp.com/sos
```

And here's the Objective-C code that is making the request:

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]
                                    initWithURL:[NSURL
                                                 URLWithString:@"http://thawing-ravine-5632.herokuapp.com/sos"]];

    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:x
   forHTTPHeaderField:@"x"];
    [request setValue:y
   forHTTPHeaderField:@"y"];
    [request setValue:type
   forHTTPHeaderField:@"type"];
    [request setValue:uid
   forHTTPHeaderField:@"uid"];

    NSURLConnection * postOutput =[[NSURLConnection alloc]
     initWithRequest:request 
     delegate:self];
```

Finally, didReceiveData Logs the following:

```
2013-03-31 20:29:32.248 THST Mobile[14720:11c03] connectionDidReceiveData {"student_found":0,"school_found":0,"officer_found":0,"text_sent":0,"uid":0,"x":0.0,"y":0.0,"type":null}
```

But logging the variables before the request is made shows that they are indeed instantiated in the app prior to making the request. SSHing into the server shows that they are all just either nil or empty strings when the request is received. So something is wrong with my Objective-C code for making the post request - probably with the way I'm setting the parameters?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're setting the values as headers, not as request's body.

```
NSString *params = @"x=1&y=bla&z=foo";
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setHTTPBody:[params dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```